# Associating a number of FactorGirl models with one master 'Company' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, factory-bot

I've been using factory girl in RSPEC quite a bit, but this month I've been tasked with implementing Cucumber stories into our test suite. I think I may have a problem I'm not quite sure about.

Our 'main' account model is called 'Company'. Users, employees, etc. etc. belong to this. Some directly through a f/k others through delegation. Our old way of using factory-girl set up a number of instance vars of models build with Factory girl.

i.e in 'spec_helper.rb'

```
@grade_system = FactoryGirl.create(:grade_system)
@asset_size = FactoryGirl.create(:asset_size)
@asset_size.grades.create!(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:grade))
@company = FactoryGirl.create(:company, :asset_size => @asset_size, :grade_system => @grade_system)
```

This was quite dumb IMO.

I keep getting an error when trying to fix the factories with proper association that "Attribute already defined: asssociation". I'm guessing because a user created with a Factory that belongs to an employee, both built with factories that have the association :company, is causing the conflict. But this isn't the only instance. I guess my question is, what is best practice for this situation. I feel like if I could stub out a company and assign it to all of the Factories that need it, that might work, or stuff all of the proper Associations into the company Factory, but wouldn't be able to build a user with FactoryGirl.build(:user). .... Or am I just way missing the point on how associations work?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do

   sequence(:name)                    { |n|  "Company#{n}" }
   sequence(:subdomain)               { |n| "subdomain#{n}" }  
   first_time_setup                   false

   non_exempt_multiplier              1.2
   exempt_multiplier                  1.2
   executive_multiplier               1.2

   primary_contact_first_name         'Jarrett'
   primary_contact_last_name          'Green'
   primary_contact_email              'tes@test.com'
   primary_contact_phone              '(555) 555-5555'
   hours_considered_part_time         30
   hours_considered_full_time         40

   association :industry
   association :grade_system
   association :asset_size

 end
end

######################################

FactoryGirl.define do
  require 'faker'
  factory :employee do

    association :company
    association :position
    association :branch

    first_name                Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name                 'Smith'
    pay_basis                 'salary'
    current_salary            10000.00
    date_in_position          (Date.today)
    sequence(:internal_id)    { |n| n }  

    user
  end
end

############################################################

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    association :company 
    sequence(:login)          {|l|  "user#{l}@test.com"}
    sequence(:first_name)     {|fn| "UserFirstName#{fn}"}
    sequence(:last_name)      {|ln| "UserLastName#{ln}"}
    password                  'thisisthepassword'
    password_confirmation     'thisisthepassword'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show how the Factories are defined for Commpany, AssetSize, and GradeSystem?

Comment: Just edited with the factories I think are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approach to dealing with this is to use Fixtures as the parent records and then define them in the factories. Create one valid fixture per model and then you can assign it in the factory definition as follows:

```
association : grade_system { GradeSystem.find(12345678) }
```

where the number is the id of the fixture.

There are a few nice things about this approach. First, it's fast as you won't be creating the parent records every time you create a child, fixtures are loaded once at the start of the test run and persist throughout. Second it's easy, each fixture is given an `id` number based on the name of the fixture - it is always the same for every run so you can be confident in just using `find` directly - they also can link associations easily so you don't need to create parents of parents when building a factory. Third it's flexible, you can always pass in another parent if needed for testing when the factory is created or built.

You avoid most of the issues with fixtures as you only create one of each type to use as for parents.